# Problems in sculpting mode

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting

[image: FrostingProblem]

I am new to blender and have been following Blender Guru's donut tutorial. When I go in sculpting mode for the icing I always end up getting getting holes for the icing. But When I select the donut I have no problems. I have applied the solidify modifier and the subdivision. I have played with the settings. Nothing is working. The donut looks fine when I am on layout and edit mode. I can sculpt but on it but the wholes wont go away.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem before. The solution for me was to use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>  to clear any masks that might have been applied to the model by applying the modifier.

Not sure why it happens, but I think it has something to do with the *Subsurf* modifier.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I tried it and it didnt work for me.